# Sequential Criterion for Functional Limits - why proof by contrapositive?

Tags: real-analysis

**Theorem**

Given a function $f: A \to \mathbb R$ and a limit point $c$ of $A$, the following two statements are equivalent:

(i) $\lim\limits_{x \to c} f(x) = L$

(ii) For all sequences $(x_n) \subseteq A$ satisfying $x_n \neq c$ and $(x_n) \to c$, it follows that $f(x_n) \to L$.

(i) $\implies$ (ii) is fine. Every resource I consult for the proof of (ii) $\implies$ (i) uses contrapositive / contradiction, but I don't *quite* see why this is required?

Trying to be more concrete, what's wrong with the following argument?

Want to show (WTS):  $\lim\limits_{x \to c} f(x) = L$

i.e. $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0 \, $  such that if $0 < | x-c| < \delta$ (and $x \in A$) then $|f(x) - L | < \epsilon$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Since $(x_n) \to c$ we know that for any $\delta >0$ there exists an $N \in \mathbb N$ such that if $n \geq N$ then $|x_n - c| < \delta$. This gives us a $\delta$ via. $N$ (?).

For this $N$ (hence $\delta$) we thus have $0 < | x_N-c| < \delta$ (assuming $x_N \neq c$) which implies (from assuming (ii) ?) that $|f(x_N) - L | < \epsilon$.

By the way, I'm very happy to try to think for myself on this so if there's a way to hint / correct the above without giving it away please do so. Also, if what I've written is unsavable / very wrong also just feel free to point this out.

Comment: Since $(x_n) \to c$? What is $(x_n)$ here? No such sequence is given to you.

Comment: @geetha290krm Perhaps they wanted to start with an arbitrary sequence $x_n \to c$, $x_n \ne c$ for all $n\ge 1$.

Comment: @esoteric-elliptic That would make no sense if the aim is to prove ii) implies i).

Comment: @geetha290krm Agreed, the proof in its current form does nothing.

Comment: I don't understand why we can't start with an arbitrary sequence per the first part of (ii)? i.e. just like we let $\epsilon> 0$ since we're assuming (ii).